# Gatsby on Netlify build error There was an error in your GraphQL query: Data read, but end of buffer not reached

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, netlify

I have had to update my gatsby/headless wordpress site to the latest version and when trying to build I am getting the following error: There was an error in your GraphQL query: Data read, but end of buffer not reached.

When building locally the build fails but without that error message. I only get that on Netlify.

Node Version: 14.17.5
Gatsby Version: 4.6.1
WPGatsby Version: 2.2.0

Here is my full build log:

```
2:55:34 PM: Build ready to start
2:55:36 PM: build-image version: c97e5a221e3fdb93dfecc4e878977417130d2bfc (xenial)
2:55:36 PM: build-image tag: v3.10.4
2:55:36 PM: buildbot version: 94cf4881e10a7b2d529971a176d6ede22bcaeb38
2:55:36 PM: Building without cache
2:55:36 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:55:37 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
2:55:37 PM: git clone git@bitbucket.org:gatsby-wordpress-base/frontend
2:55:38 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/festivalcoast
2:55:39 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
2:55:40 PM: Starting build script
2:55:40 PM: Installing dependencies
2:55:40 PM: Python version set to 2.7
2:55:41 PM: Downloading and installing node v14.17.5...
2:55:42 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.5/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64.tar.xz...
2:55:42 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
2:55:42 PM: Checksums matched!
2:55:46 PM: Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
2:55:46 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
2:55:46 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
2:55:46 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
2:55:47 PM: Required ruby-2.7.1 is not installed - installing.
2:55:47 PM: Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
2:55:48 PM: Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/16.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
2:55:48 PM: Checking requirements for ubuntu.
2:55:48 PM: Requirements installation successful.
2:55:48 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #configure
2:55:48 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #download
2:55:49 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #validate archive
2:55:54 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #extract
2:55:57 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #validate binary
2:55:58 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #setup
2:55:59 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@global
2:55:59 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #importing gemset /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems........................................
2:55:59 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #generating global wrappers........
2:55:59 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1
2:56:00 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #importing gemsetfile /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
2:56:00 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #generating default wrappers........
2:56:01 PM: Using /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1
2:56:01 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
2:56:01 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
2:56:01 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
2:56:01 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
2:56:02 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.14
2:56:50 PM: npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
2:56:50 PM: > msgpackr-extract@1.0.16 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/msgpackr-extract
2:56:50 PM: > node-gyp-build
2:56:50 PM: > lmdb-store@1.6.14 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/lmdb-store
2:56:50 PM: > node-gyp-build
2:56:51 PM: > sharp@0.29.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/sharp
2:56:51 PM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
2:56:53 PM: sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.11.3/libvips-8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.br
2:56:55 PM: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
2:56:55 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2:56:55 PM: > core-js@3.21.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
2:56:55 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2:56:55 PM: > core-js-pure@3.21.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js-pure
2:56:55 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2:56:56 PM: > gatsby-telemetry@3.6.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
2:56:56 PM: > node src/postinstall.js || true
2:56:56 PM: > gatsby-cli@4.6.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-cli
2:56:56 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
2:56:56 PM: > gatsby@4.6.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby
2:56:56 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
2:56:58 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
2:56:58 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2:56:58 PM: added 1885 packages from 1048 contributors and audited 1891 packages in 56.02s
2:57:00 PM: 186 packages are looking for funding
2:57:00 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
2:57:00 PM: found 21 vulnerabilities (13 moderate, 6 high, 2 critical)
2:57:00 PM:   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2:57:00 PM: NPM modules installed
2:57:01 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
2:57:01 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
2:57:01 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:57:01 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:57:01 PM: Installing missing commands
2:57:01 PM: Verify run directory
2:57:02 PM: ​
2:57:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:02 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
2:57:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:02 PM: ​
2:57:02 PM: ❯ Version
2:57:02 PM:   @netlify/build 26.2.2
2:57:02 PM: ​
2:57:02 PM: ❯ Flags
2:57:02 PM:   baseRelDir: true
2:57:02 PM:   buildId: 61fa9b66bcf5840068d8c00e
2:57:02 PM:   deployId: 61fa9b66bcf5840068d8c010
2:57:03 PM: ​
2:57:03 PM: ❯ Current directory
2:57:03 PM:   /opt/build/repo
2:57:03 PM: ​
2:57:03 PM: ❯ Config file
2:57:03 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
2:57:03 PM: ​
2:57:03 PM: ❯ Context
2:57:03 PM:   production
2:57:03 PM: ​
2:57:03 PM: ❯ Installing plugins
2:57:03 PM:    - netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache@0.3.0
2:57:04 PM: ​
2:57:04 PM: ❯ Loading plugins
2:57:04 PM:    - netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache@0.3.0 from Netlify app
2:57:05 PM: ​
2:57:05 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:05 PM:   1. netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache (onPreBuild event)             
2:57:05 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:05 PM: ​
2:57:05 PM: No Gatsby cache found. Building fresh.
2:57:05 PM: ​
2:57:05 PM: (netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache onPreBuild completed in 17ms)
2:57:05 PM: ​
2:57:05 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:05 PM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
2:57:05 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:57:05 PM: ​
2:57:05 PM: $ npm run build
2:57:05 PM: > gatsby-wordpress-base-frontend@1.0.0 build /opt/build/repo
2:57:05 PM: > gatsby build
2:57:10 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins - 2.353s
2:57:10 PM: success onPreInit - 0.005s
2:57:11 PM: success initialize cache - 0.224s
2:57:11 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.076s
2:57:11 PM: success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.319s
2:57:11 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.331s
2:57:12 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ensuring plugin requirements are met - 1.353s
2:57:13 PM: ⠀
2:57:13 PM: info  gatsby-source-wordpress 
2:57:13 PM:     This is either your first build or the cache was cleared.
2:57:13 PM:     Please wait while your WordPress data is synced to your Gatsby cache.
2:57:13 PM:     Maybe now's a good time to get up and stretch? :D
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema - 2.031s
2:57:15 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 3.420s
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Comment - 0.559s - fetched 0
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Category - 0.620s - fetched 2
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  MenuItem - 0.649s - fetched 9
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  PostFormat - 0.806s - fetched 0
2:57:15 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Menu - 0.818s - fetched 2
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Tag - 0.975s - fetched 0
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  UserRole - 1.040s - fetched 0
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Page - 1.090s - fetched 4
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ContentType - 1.242s - fetched 3
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Taxonomy - 1.267s - fetched 3
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  User - 1.326s - fetched 2
2:57:16 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Post - 1.675s - fetched 6
2:57:19 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  MediaItems - 3.441s - fetched 0
2:57:19 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetch root fields - 4.201s
2:57:25 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  MediaItem - 8.924s - fetched 13
2:57:25 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  creating nodes - 8.925s
2:57:25 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetching nodes - 10.609s - 44 total
2:57:25 PM: success Downloading remote files - 9.218s - 17/17 1.84/s
2:57:25 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
2:57:25 PM: success source and transform nodes - 10.800s
2:57:26 PM: info Writing GraphQL type definitions to /opt/build/repo/.cache/schema.gql
2:57:27 PM: success building schema - 2.089s
2:57:28 PM: warning You can't use childImageSharp together with bcp-logo.svg — use publicURL instead. The childImageSharp portion of the query in this file will return null:
undefined
2:57:29 PM: success createPages - 1.654s
2:57:32 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 3.225s
2:57:32 PM: info Total nodes: 146, SitePage nodes: 14 (use --verbose for breakdown)
2:57:32 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
2:57:32 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
2:57:34 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas - 0.977s
2:57:37 PM: success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema - 4.873s
2:57:48 PM: success extract queries from components - 15.504s
2:57:48 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.051s
2:57:57 PM: success Build manifest and related icons - 9.078s
2:57:57 PM: success onPostBootstrap - 9.102s
2:57:57 PM: info bootstrap finished - 51.563s
2:57:57 PM: success write out requires - 0.010s
2:58:31 PM: DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
2:58:31 PM: Recommendation: math.div(4em, 3) or calc(4em / 3)
2:58:31 PM: More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
2:58:31 PM:   ╷
2:58:31 PM: 6 │   font-size: (4em / 3);
2:58:31 PM:   │               ^^^^^^^
2:58:31 PM:   ╵
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/_larger.scss 6:15     @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/fontawesome.scss 8:9  @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/style.scss 5:9                           root stylesheet
2:58:31 PM: DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
2:58:31 PM: Recommendation: math.div(3em, 4) or calc(3em / 4)
2:58:31 PM: More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
2:58:31 PM:   ╷
2:58:31 PM: 7 │   line-height: (3em / 4);
2:58:31 PM:   │                 ^^^^^^^
2:58:31 PM:   ╵
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/_larger.scss 7:17     @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/fontawesome.scss 8:9  @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/style.scss 5:9                           root stylesheet
2:58:31 PM: DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
2:58:31 PM: Recommendation: math.div($fa-li-width * 5, 4) or calc($fa-li-width * 5 / 4)
2:58:31 PM: More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
2:58:31 PM:   ╷
2:58:31 PM: 6 │   margin-left: $fa-li-width * 5/4;
2:58:31 PM:   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:58:31 PM:   ╵
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/_list.scss 6:16        @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/styles/fontawesome/fontawesome.scss 10:9  @import
2:58:31 PM:     src/style.scss 5:9                            root stylesheet
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/cover.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/columns.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/row.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/image.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/embed.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/media-text.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
2:59:59 PM: warning chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
2:59:59 PM: Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/components/post-tease.scss
2:59:59 PM: despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
2:59:59 PM:  * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[11].oneOf[1].use[3]!./src/styles/blocks/gallery.scss
2:59:59 PM:    - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-js, component---src-templates-page-js
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) component---src-templates-blog-post-archive-js
2:59:59 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 121.595s
3:01:46 PM: success Building HTML renderer - 107.492s
3:01:46 PM: success Execute page configs - 0.035s
3:01:46 PM: success Caching Webpack compilations - 0.001s
3:01:49 PM: error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
3:01:49 PM: Data read, but end of buffer not reached
3:01:49 PM:   26 |       }
3:01:49 PM:   27 |       categories {
3:01:49 PM:   28 |         nodes {
3:01:49 PM:   29 |           link
3:01:49 PM:   30 |           name
3:01:49 PM:   31 |           slug
3:01:49 PM:   32 |         }
3:01:49 PM:   33 |       }
3:01:49 PM:   34 |     }
3:01:49 PM:   35 |   }
3:01:49 PM: > 36 |   allWpTermNode {
3:01:49 PM:      |   ^
3:01:49 PM:   37 |     categories: nodes {
3:01:49 PM:   38 |       ... on WpCategory {
3:01:49 PM:   39 |         id
3:01:49 PM:   40 |         name
3:01:49 PM:   41 |         link
3:01:49 PM:   42 |         slug
3:01:49 PM:   43 |       }
3:01:49 PM:   44 |     }
3:01:49 PM:   45 |   }
3:01:49 PM:   46 |   page: wpPage(id: {eq: $id}) {
3:01:49 PM: File path: /opt/build/repo/src/templates/blog-post-archive.js
3:01:49 PM: Url path: /blogs-news
3:01:49 PM: Plugin: none
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM:   Error: Data read, but end of buffer not reached
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - node.cjs:178 checkedRead
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[msgpackr]/dist/node.cjs:178:10
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - node.cjs:91 Packr.unpack
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[msgpackr]/dist/node.cjs:91:10
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - node.cjs:150 Packr.decode
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[msgpackr]/dist/node.cjs:150:15
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - index.js:440 Object.get
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[lmdb-store]/index.js:440:63
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - caching.js:37 Object.get
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[lmdb-store]/caching.js:37:17
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - lmdb-datastore.ts:148 getNode
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/lmdb/lmdb-datastore.ts:148:16
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - lmdb-datastore.ts:127 
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/lmdb/lmdb-datastore.ts:127:52
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - ArrayLikeIterable.js:36 Object.next
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[lmdb-store]/util/ArrayLikeIterable.js:36:16
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - ArrayLikeIterable.js:27 Object.value [as next]
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[lmdb-store]/util/ArrayLikeIterable.js:27:34
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - iterable.ts:45 GatsbyIterable.forEach
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/common/iterable.ts:45:16
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - indexing.ts:258 ensureEmptyFilterCache
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/in-memory/indexing.ts:258:8
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - run-fast-filters.ts:336 convertAndApplyFastFilters
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/in-memory/run-fast-filters.ts:336:7
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - run-fast-filters.ts:282 runFastFiltersAndSort
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/in-memory/run-fast-filters.ts:282:18
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - lmdb-datastore.ts:176 Object.runQuery
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/datastore/lmdb/lmdb-datastore.ts:176:26
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - node-model.js:347 LocalNodeModel._query
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/schema/node-model.js:347:58
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
3:01:49 PM:     internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM: error An error occurred during parallel query running.
3:01:49 PM: Go here for troubleshooting tips: https://gatsby.dev/pqr-feedback
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM:   Error: Worker exited before finishing task
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - index.js:113 ChildProcess.<anonymous>
3:01:49 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-worker]/dist/index.js:113:45
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM:   - child_process.js:277 Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
3:01:49 PM:     internal/child_process.js:277:12
3:01:49 PM:   
3:01:49 PM: 
3:01:49 PM: not finished Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 269.864s
3:01:49 PM: not finished run queries in workers - 2.771s
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! gatsby-wordpress-base-frontend@1.0.0 build: `gatsby build`
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR!
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-wordpress-base-frontend@1.0.0 build script.
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
3:01:49 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-02-02T15_01_49_927Z-debug.log
3:01:50 PM: ​
3:01:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:01:50 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
3:01:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:01:50 PM: ​
3:01:50 PM:   Error message
3:01:50 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
3:01:50 PM: ​
3:01:50 PM:   Error location
3:01:50 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
3:01:50 PM:   npm run build
3:01:50 PM: ​
3:01:50 PM:   Resolved config
3:01:50 PM:   build:
3:01:50 PM:     command: npm run build
3:01:50 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
3:01:50 PM:     environment:
3:01:50 PM:       - GATSBY_CPU_COUNT
3:01:50 PM:       - GATSBY_WPADMIN_URL
3:01:50 PM:       - GATSBY_WP_AJAX_URL
3:01:50 PM:       - NODE_VERSION
3:01:50 PM:       - WPGRAPHQL_URL
3:01:50 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
3:01:50 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
3:01:50 PM:   plugins:
3:01:50 PM:     - inputs: {}
3:01:50 PM:       origin: ui
3:01:50 PM:       package: netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache
3:01:50 PM: Caching artifacts
3:01:50 PM: Started saving node modules
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving node modules
3:01:50 PM: Started saving build plugins
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving build plugins
3:01:50 PM: Started saving pip cache
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving pip cache
3:01:50 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
3:01:50 PM: Started saving go dependencies
3:01:50 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
3:01:54 PM: Cached ruby version 2.7.1
3:01:54 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:01:54 PM: Creating deploy upload records
3:01:54 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
3:01:54 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:01:54 PM: Finished processing build request in 6m18.406894694s
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with an outdated dependancy of msgpackr. Installing the latest version as a main dependency fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue very easily.

```
For npm =  npm run clean 
&&
For Yarn = yarn clean.
```

I just resolved the issue by yarn clean and than yarn start than issue just vanished.